# Understanding collisions with custom hashing

Tags: python, random, collision

I'm using the following in my application:

```
base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str(random.getrandbits(20))).lower().replace('=', '')
```

Minus the aesthetic changes:

```
base64.urlsafe_b64encode(str(random.getrandbits(20))
```

How do I go about finding out the likelihood of collision?

Answer (score 0):

It's the same likelihood of one `random.getrandbits(20)` colliding with another since the outer functions are deterministic.

If the output of `random.getrandbits` are in fact, random -- the chance of one colliding with another is 1/(2^20) or ... about ***1 in a million***

For n entries, the chance that an additional entry (entry n+1) collides is n/(2^20).  So the probability grows linearly with the number of entries in the dictionary.  At 1,048,576 entries, it is guaranteed that the next entry will collide.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2^20 different possible random values.  Thus, the probability of two given random values being equal is 1/(2^20), or about **1 in a million**.

However, if you are creating multiple values, then due to the [birthday paradox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) you will only need to generate about 2^10 or about **one thousand different values** to have a 50% chance of two of them being equal!

To avoid this, I would recommend at least 128-bits.  This requires about 2^64 (~18 billion billion) values before having a 50% chance of collision.  When encoded into base-64, this would be 22-characters long.